# Allow roles and policy to access controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, controller, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

Right now I decorate a method like this to allow "Reader" to access my controller action using policy.

```
[Authorize(Policy = Policy.Reader)]
```

**How can I allow Reader Role to access the same method?** For example I wanted to give access to both Reader Policy and Reader Role.

```
[Authorize(Roles = Role.Reader)] 
and 
[Authorize(Policy = Policy.Reader)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  multiple Authorize attributes to specify the role and policy

**Example:**

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Role")]  
[Authorize(Policy = "Policy")]  
public IActionResult MultipleAccess()  
{  
    return View("Page");  
}
```

if you want to add custom roles you may try this

**Example:**

```
public static class CustomRoles
{
    public const string Administrator = "Administrador";
    public const string User = "user";
}

[Authorize(Roles = CustomRoles.Administrator +","+ CustomRoles.User)]
```

For more details refer this [document](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/policy-based-role-based-authorization-in-asp-net-core/)